# Киот (?) расположен на стене дома или в стене?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Впрочем, почти у каждого здания в Риме есть свой покровитель. И
>   нередко **на стене дома расположен киот**, который сохраняет
>   живописное или скульптурное изображение Мадонны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**КИОТ**
1. ***Углубление для иконы в стене.***
2. Застекленная рама-шкафчик для крупной иконы или нескольких небольших икон.
[**Словарь храмового зодчества**](https://temple_architecture.academic.ru/166)

Думаю, что в Вашем предложении имеется в виду именно *углубление **в** стене.*

[Кронштадтская крепость. Форт Шанец. Киот в стене каземата](https://%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4.%D1%80%D1%84/o-proekte/novosti/itogi-fotokonkursa-%C2%ABosennij-marafon%C2%BB.html)

Comment: Таки ***в*** стене...

Comment: Лорочка, напишите мне: linaglat@mail.ru - просто связь установим.

Answer (score 1):

Киот (остеклённый шкаф-витринка) можно повесить **на** плоской стене и можно поместить его в нише стены, но тем не менее — ниша в стене, а киот **на** стене.